# Automatically Run a method in Excel AddIn every hour (not via VBA)

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

My Excel AddIn is written in C#, ExcelDNA, NetOffice. 
There is one method which retrieves hourly data from a server and display in Excel.

I want a way to retrieve data from server every hour.  We do not want to use VBA since it is a hassle for end users.

Can someone point me to right link or path?

THanks

Edit

My method is NOT a UDF,  say a user enters in formula bar =MyMethod(sym1, other params)
he has to click "GetData" button to get data from web service. It is a manual process. 
Now what I want,  once the formula MyMethod is entered and manulally "GetData" once, I want a way to "GetData" every hour afterwards so the user do not have to do it manually. 
I thought of a timer, but if the process is called an hour later and try to plot data to Excel but Excel is busy doing something, the plot will fail. So maybe there is other way? thanks

Comment: This is unclear... you have a service that already pulls the hourly data and drops it into Excel.  Now you want to pull the same data again and display it somewhere else?

Comment: Not sure why VBA is "a hassle for end users"; it seems you already have one addin, what's wrong with having two? It's the built in mechanism for Excel - why not take advantage of it?

Comment: Thanks, many end users do not know VBA. That's why we want to avoid

Comment: Are you looking to do a top-down refactor of all the code or just this one method?  If the former, I would suggest creating a webpage that you can write the data to and **then** feed it to an Excel document on demand.  That is just me, though.  Oh, and thank you for the edit!

Comment: If you use the Excel-DNA helper ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueMacro from your timer event, you should not have problems if Excel is 'busy' (the macro will only run when Excel is ready).

Comment: Another approach is to use an RTD Server or Reactive Extensions IObservable (via Excel-DNA's RxExcel helper) to push the data directly to the UDF (your GetData button might then become an enable / disable for the feed).

Comment: @Govert, thank you very much. Do you have examples of both approaches? Thanks

Comment: Yes - check the Async examples in the Excel-DNA distribution.

Comment: @Govert. Thank you very much. I also found some examples from http://exceldna.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Run a scheduled task which executes Excel and opens the file which has an additional VBA macro invoked upon the Workbook_Open event.